# accessing elements inside a data template in xaml

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

i have a data template which have 2 text blocks and 1 button i need to access the button id to fetch specific data for every data template but the problem is the the button is not accessible from the c# code

here is my XAML code   for the data template

```
          <DataTemplate x:Key="CityItemTemplate">

                  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="8" Background="#FF003847" Width="320">

                <StackPanel Margin="4">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="NameBlock" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Content}" FontSize="38" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,4,0"  Grid.Column="1" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DescriptionBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,4,0" Grid.Column="1" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" MaxHeight="168"/>
                    <Button  x:Uid="{Binding idb}" x:Name="b12" Content="download&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" Height="87" Click="b1_click"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and i need to know which button was clicked also ?

Answer (score 0):

Then u can use button event handler b1_click. In sender parameter you have a reference to the currently pressed button. The buttons are difficult to distinguish because they have same names.

```
private void b12_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

If you want to know which data is "linked" to button (uid, content etc. ) use Command and CommandParameter instead of event handler.

Xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Name="mainPage">

<!-- New button in template -->

<Button  x:Uid="{Binding idb}" x:Name="b12" Content="download" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" Height="87" 
         Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, ElementName=mainPage}" 
         CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }

public MyViewModel()
{    
    ButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand<CityItem>(e => ButtonClickExecute(e));
}

public void ButtonClickExecute(object parameter)
{
    CityItem cityItem = parameter as CityItem;
}
```

When you clicked the button, this fires ButtonClickExecute. In parameter you have source CityItem object and now you can determine which button was clicked. RelayCommand come from MVVM Light Toolkit see nuget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but i need to know which button was clicked ?!